# LDA topicmodel, how can I see the terms in the result

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I follow this post to do `Topic Analysis`:

[A gentle introduction to topic modeling using R](https://eight2late.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/a-gentle-introduction-to-topic-modeling-using-r/)

I want to view the terms, which should be in `ldaOut.terms`, however, I see numbers instead of terms. How to view the terms?

```
ldaOut.terms

Topic 1 Topic 2 Topic 3 Topic 4 Topic 5 Topic 6 Topic 7 Topic 8 Topic 9 Topic 10
[1,] "38"    "85"    "4"     "79"    "29"    "43"    "13"    "81"    "70"    "39"
```

Comment: Lots of good stuff on topic modelling with R here: https://github.com/trinker/topicmodels_learning

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem is my dtm, so I created a dtm like this

```
 dtm <- create_matrix(ss, language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE,     stemWords=TRUE, weighting=weightTf)
```

problem solved